# AWS Elastic beanstalk and Bitbucket pipeline deployment version mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, .net-6.0, bitbucket-pipelines

I have pipeline setup to build and deploy to **Elastic Beanstalk** Environment

The project I am deploying is **.NET 6**

The environment specification in in Elastic Beanstalk is:
-Platform: .NET Core on Linux
-Platform Branch: .NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
-Platform version: **2.3.5**

This is the Pipe I use in bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
- pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:1.0.2
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: 'release.zip'
                VERSION_LABEL: 'pipeline-testing-deploy-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER'
                WAIT: 'true'
```

Everything works fine but recently Elastic Beanstalk suggested I change the Platform version to 2.5.1 and when I create new environment via AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2022 it defaults to this version as well.

The problem is when I use version **2.5.1** bitbucket pipeline run returns error:

✖ Deployment failed. Environment environment-name is running a different version pipeline-test-deploy-239.

I tried looking for updated Pipe for bitbucket pipeline but there doesn't seem to be much development done in the project of the [pipe](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy/src/master/)

I tried looking for updated Pipe for bitbucket pipeline but there doesn't seem to be much development done in the project of the pipe